# $\aleph_a^{cf(\aleph_a)} = \aleph_{a+1}$ for $\aleph_a$ regular assuming GCH

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

$\aleph_a^{cf(\aleph_a)} = \aleph_{a+1}$ for $\aleph_a$ regular assuming GCH

$\aleph_a$ regular, so $cf(\aleph_a) = \aleph_a$.

Assuming GCH $2^{\aleph_a} = \aleph_{a+1}$ holds.

But I'm missing the argument for $\aleph_a^{\aleph_a} = 2^{\aleph_a}$. I guess I'm just blind right now. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

It is a general fact of cardinal exponentiation that if $2 \leq \kappa \leq \lambda$ and $\lambda$ is infinite, then $\kappa^\lambda = 2^\lambda$.  The proof is quite simple: $$2^\lambda \leq \kappa^\lambda \leq ( 2^\kappa )^\lambda = 2^{\kappa \lambda} = 2^\lambda.$$ 
As you have noted, in your case you have $\mathrm{cf} ( \aleph_a ) = \aleph_a$, since $\aleph_a$ is regular, and so the above is applicable.

Comment: So here and in the above version I need:
$(2^a)^b = 2^{ab} = 2^b$ for $b$ infinite.
Right?

Comment: @mathematikerlein: For $b \leq a$ and $a$ infinite; yes.  (And this is just because of the cardinal multiplication.)

Comment: Ok, forgot this feature of cardinal multiplication..

Comment: @mathematikerlein: It's one of the main reasons I'm thinking of teaching my children (infinite) cardinal addition/multiplication before ordinary addition/multiplication!  j/k (sort of)

Comment: Nice using your uberpowers to comment on deleted posts! See you next week!

Answer (score 2):

If we assume $\sf GCH$ then $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ for every $\kappa$, including singular ones.

We have that if $\kappa$ is regular then, $$2^\kappa\leq\kappa^\kappa\leq(2^\kappa)^\kappa=2^\kappa$$

On the other hand if $\kappa$ is singular then $$\kappa<\kappa^+\leq\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}\leq\kappa^\kappa=2^\kappa=\kappa^+$$

In either case, if we assume $\sf GCH$ we have that $\kappa^\kappa=\kappa^+$.